# Ambiguity for the pyspark reduce method

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
def reduce(self, f):                                             #1 parameter
    def func(iterator): 
        iterator = iter(iterator) 
        try: 
            initial = next(iterator) 
        except StopIteration: 
            return 
        yield reduce(f, iterator, initial)                             #3 parameter 

    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect() 
    if vals: 
        return reduce(f, vals)                                         #2 parameter 
    raise ValueError("Can not reduce() empty RDD")
```

The reduce function only takes 1 parameter, but it gives 2 or 3 parameters.

I search the whole python code without any other definition about reduce.

Answer (score 4):

`reduce()` there is a method.  It is not in the global namespace; it is just an attribute of a class or instance.  When it calls `reduce()`, it is not recursion; it is calling the built-in function [reduce()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reduce).  If it wanted to call the `reduce()` being defined here, it would need to use `self.reduce(...)`.  The *built-in* function `reduce()` can take two or three parameters.  If given two, it will apply the first argument, a function, with two arguments: the first two elements of the second argument, a sequence.  It then calls the function with what it returned and the third element in the sequence, and it continues like that until the sequence is exhausted.  When a third argument is given, it is given as the first argument and the first element in the sequence is given as the second argument.  Next time, it is the returns of that and the second element in the sequence, and it continues from there.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by zondo, *the first* reduce is not in the global namespace.
It is just an attribute of a class or instance.
Internally to reduce's class definition is called the built in python method [reduce()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=reduce#functools.reduce).

In python when you use the built in reduce method with three parameter, like this:

```
reduce(myfunction, list, init)
```

You are asking to apply a reduce *myfunction* on *list*, with *init* as initial value.

Comment: Like a `fold` from Scala.